# Binary Indexed Tree : How to find index with given Cumulative frequency

Tags: algorithm, tree, binary-search

I was trying to find the Index with a given cumulative frequency in a Binary Indexed Tree (BIT).

I was able to solve this problem in O(log(n)*log(n)) by implementing it with the help of binary search and a function which calculates the Cumulative frequency at any index.

But I was thinking of solving this problem in O(log(n)).

So please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This algorithm from a [topcoder tutorial](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees) shows how to find the greatest index with a given cumulative frequency in O(logn):

> The naive and most simple solution for finding an index with a given cumultive frequency is just simply iterating through all indexes, calculating cumulative frequency, and checking if it's equal to the given value. In case of negative frequencies it is the only solution. However, if we have only non-negative frequencies in our tree (that means cumulative frequencies for greater indexes are not smaller) we can figure out logarithmic algorithm, which is modification of binary search. We go through all bits (starting with the highest one), make the index, compare the cumulative frequency of the current index and given value and, according to the outcome, take the lower or higher half of the interval (just like in binary search).

```
// if in tree exists more than one index with a same
// cumulative frequency, this procedure will return 
// the greatest one
int findG(int cumFre){
    int idx = 0;

    while ((bitMask != 0) && (idx < MaxVal)){
        int tIdx = idx + bitMask;
        if (cumFre >= tree[tIdx]){ 
            // if current cumulative frequency is equal to cumFre, 
            // we are still looking for higher index (if exists)
            idx = tIdx;
            cumFre -= tree[tIdx];
        }
        bitMask >>= 1;
    }
    if (cumFre != 0)
        return -1;
    else
        return idx;
}
```

Comment: I think it is important to note that this only works when the frequencies are non-negative.

Comment: In the above code the initial value of bitMask is the greatest bit of Maxval.

Comment: What does the greatest bit of MaxVal mean? If MaxVal of 15, bitMask would be 16? And what if MaxVal was 17, still bitMask is still 16 right?